# dynamically added hyperlink in table click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am adding dynamically hyperlink and want to execute click event as below when ever user clicked on it but it is not firing up.

```
 <table id="assinged_areas" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-condensed">
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```

When user selected some option  in DropDown then it goes and get areas from server then ajax get calls this function by passing data to this function

```
 function updateAssignedAreas(data) {

            debugger;
            var areas = data.split(',');
            $.each(areas, function (i, item) {
                $('#assinged_areas > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td>' + '<a class=\'btn btn-danger\'><i class=\'fa fa-minus-circle\'></i></a>'
                    + '</td></tr>');
            });
        }
```

This is the function when user click on unassign must call but not firing at all

```
  $('.btn-danger').click(function (parameters) {
            debugger;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamic elements

```
$("#assinged_areas").on("click", '.btn-danger', function (parameters) {
    var row=$(this).closest("tr");
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html()); //will get the inner text of first td
});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

Comment: as Anoop says, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, How can I get the row details of the clicked button

Comment: @ineffablep can you share the final rendered html?

Comment: @ineffablep see the edits